# How can we create an Azure VM with trusted launch enabled with Azure Java SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk, azure-java-sdk

Like the title suggests, I've spent some time reading sdk documents and testing but had no luck so far finding a method under `AzureResourceManager.virtualMachine` would allow me to explicitly set the VM to enable trusted launch feature at creation.

It is possible to specify `SecurityProfile` with `VirtualMachineInner` class but I have no clues at all passing the object to call the `create()` method under `AzureResourceManager.virtualMachine`.

Here's a short snippet I came up with so far.

```
SecurityProfile securityProfile = new SecurityProfile()
            .withSecurityType(SecurityTypes.TRUSTED_LAUNCH)
            .withUefiSettings(new UefiSettings().withSecureBootEnabled(true).withVTpmEnabled(true))
            .withEncryptionAtHost(true);
VirtualMachineInner vmi = new VirtualMachineInner();
vmi.withSecurityProfile(securityProfile);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VirtualMachineInner` class represents the internal properties of the VM and is not to be used directly for creating or managing virtual machines using the Azure Java SDK.

- Use the fluent builder pattern provided by the `VirtualMachine.DefinitionStages.WithCreate` interface that define and it creates the virtual machine, then configure Trusted Launch settings separately after the virtual machine is created.

```java
import com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.models.SecurityProfile;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.models.SecurityTypes;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.models.UefiSettings;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.models.VirtualMachine;
import com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.models.VirtualMachineSizeTypes;

// Create a SecurityProfile with Trusted Launch settings
SecurityProfile securityProfile = new SecurityProfile()
        .withSecurityType(SecurityTypes.TRUSTED_LAUNCH)
        .withUefiSettings(new UefiSettings().withSecureBootEnabled(true).withVTpmEnabled(true))
        .withEncryptionAtHost(true);

// Create the virtual machine using the Azure Java SDK
VirtualMachine virtualMachine = azureResourceManager.virtualMachines()
        .define(vmName)
        .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
        .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
        .withNewPrimaryNetwork(network)
        .withPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
        .withNewPublicIPAddress()
        .withPopularLinuxImage(knownLinuxImage)
        .withRootUsername(vmUsername)
        .withSsh(publicKey)
        .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_D2_V2)
        .withOSDiskStorageAccountType(StorageAccountTypes.PREMIUM_LRS)
        .create();

// Configure Trusted Launch settings separately for the virtual machine
azureResourceManager.virtualMachines()
        .manager()
        .virtualMachineExtensionImages()
        .register("Microsoft.Compute", "TrustedLaunchExtension", "1.0")
        .beginCreateOrUpdate(
                resourceGroupName,
                virtualMachine.name(),
                "TrustedLaunchExtension",
                new VirtualMachineExtensionInner()
                        .withLocation(virtualMachine.regionName())
                        .withPublisher("Microsoft.Compute")
                        .withType("TrustedLaunchExtension")
                        .withVirtualMachineExtensionType("TrustedLaunchExtension")
                        .withAutoUpgradeMinorVersion(true)
                        .withSettings(securityProfile)
        )
        .waitForCompletion();
```

I tried using the `VirtualMachine.DefinitionStages.WithCreate.withTrustedLaunch()` method to enable Trusted Launch.  but unable to do it.

- `withTrustedLaunch()` method is not available in the Azure Java SDK for enabling Trusted Launch during the creation of a virtual machine.

There is a [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/trusted-launch-portal?tabs=portal%2Cportal2%2Cportal3) quoting that we can set secure boot parameter by SDK after VM creation.

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Later on I found out withTrustedLaunch() was actually available with the newest azure sdk. And I was using the spring azure sdk earlier which does not have such method and caused confusions.